# Find indels between two short sequences

Tags: samtools, indel, blastn

I have two sequences, say AAAGCTCGAGG and AAAGCGAGG. I need a convenient tool which shows me insertions or deletions between these, i.e. in this case something like

```
AAAGCTCGAGG
|||||  ||||
AAAGC  GAGG
2bp deletion starting at base pair 5
```

and also insertions such as

```
AAAGCTC GAGG
||||||| ||||
AAAGCTCTGAGG
1bp insertion at base pair 7
```

Does something like that exist? Blastn finds the alignment of course, but only outputs the *number* of gaps, not their *position*. I guess I could parse a pileup, but do not want to create a bam file from one of the sequences first, so samtools seems to be out. Any further ideas?

Comment: IMO you need to write custom code. I just done this (again) via pandas, albeit elegant its a lot of code. Its quite easy to do via Perl5.

Answer (score 1):

Smith-Waterman is guaranteed to give you the best alignment given your choice of substitution matrix.  For a few such tiny sequences, it's what I would use.  Many implementations exist.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like `SearchIO` to parse the output of BLAST, to get the desired alignment attributes: https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SearchIO.BlastIO-module.html

Answer (score 0):

blastn should be able to output this format of alignment result, using the `--outfmt 0` option

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you don't want a BAM output format? If the sequences are sufficiently long, then the CIGAR field from the SAM output of minimap2 could be used:

```
minimap2 -a seq1.fa seq2.fa | samtools view | awk '{print $6}'
```